# Python \xYZ characters in console

Tags: python, string, escaping, hex

I'm building a program that takes two files and after some processing, I have to compare some sections of the files.

As an example, When I print both strings I'm trying to compare, it looks like this:

```
CSV = 'UC013. MANTER ITEM DE NOTA FISCAL / NOTA DE SERVI\xc3\x87O / RECIBO'
DOC = 'UC013. MANTER ITEM DE NOTA FISCAL / NOTA DE SERVI\xc7O / RECIBO'
```

Both should be the same:

```
'UC013. MANTER ITEM DE NOTA FISCAL / NOTA DE SERVIÇO / RECIBO'
```

How can I print the right characters in the console and properly compare the strings?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two files with different encodings, the first is utf-8 (`CSV`), the second latin1 (`DOC`). If you want to compare them, you have to decode them to unicode first:

```
CSV = 'UC013. MANTER ITEM DE NOTA FISCAL / NOTA DE SERVI\xc3\x87O / RECIBO'
DOC = 'UC013. MANTER ITEM DE NOTA FISCAL / NOTA DE SERVI\xc7O / RECIBO'
CSV = CSV.decode('utf-8')
DOC = DOC.decode('latin1')
print(CSV == DOC)    # True
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Now I get both strings with the same encoding, but when I print them on the console, I still get somethin like this: 'UC019. MANTER PRODUTO - CONFEC\xc7\xc3O'. I should be able to print the character properly with CSV.decode('unicode_escape'), but I get: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 25-26: ordinal not in range(128). Any help please?

Comment: I noticed that my logging module is the one that's broken... If I just use print, it works fine... I'm not sure how to fix that though. Thanks a lot for our help!

Comment: python doesn't like if you try to write non-ascii characters to a console that doesn't support it. which console and os are you using? if python can't determine which encoding your console uses (usually by looking at the `LANG` environment variable), `sys.stdout.encoding` defaults to `ANSI_X3.4-1968`. Try to set a sensible output encoding...